# C: Copying a text file into a linked list results in an exception: Exception thrown: read access violation. current was 0x2C2DE900

Tags: c, linked-list, text-files

Edit: Question Was Updated For The New Problem That Occurred :|

Now, after fixing the last problem, I just fall on another one. After copying the frame after the head. The function "addFrame" throws an exception shown in the Title :(

This is the text file i copy from

```
T1
C:\opencv\GIF Project\Photos\Tank_1.jpg
1000
T2
C:\opencv\GIF Project\Photos\Tank_2.jpg
1000
T3
C:\opencv\GIF Project\Photos\Tank_3.jpg
1000
```

The Copying function:

```
/*
    loadGIF: This function loads the GIF from the text file
    Input: char filePath[STRING_SIZE = 50]: The path to the text file
    frameNode* head: The head of the linked list which we load the GIF into
    Output: None
*/
void loadGIF(char filePath[], frameNode** head)
{
    frameNode* temp = NULL;
    FILE* file = fopen(filePath, "r");
    char name[STRING_MAX] = { 0 }, path[STRING_MAX] = { 0 }, line[STRING_MAX] = { 0 };
    int counter = 0, sleep = 0, i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        if (counter == THREE)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            strcpy(name, line);
            name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
        }
        if (counter == ONE)
        {
            strcpy(path, line);
            path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = 0;
        }
        if (counter == TWO)
        {
            sleep = line;
            atoi(sleep);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                *head = createFrame(name, path, sleep);
            }
            else
            {
                temp = createFrame(name, path, sleep);
                addFrame(&head, temp);
            }
            i++;
        }
        //memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        //memset(path, 0, sizeof(path));
        counter++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

The part of the main in which I call the function:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0, choise = -1, newGif = -1, sleep = 0, place = 0;
    char path[STRING_MAX] = { 0 }, name[STRING_MAX] = { 0 };
    frameNode* head = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    newGif = loadingFunction();
    if (newGif == 1)
    {
        printf("Enter The Path To The Text File Which Holds The GIF's Data: \n");
        fgets(path, STRING_MAX, stdin);
        path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = 0;
        loadGIF(path, &head);
    }
// The rest doesn't matter
}
```

This is the addFrame function:

```
/*
    addFrame: This function addes a new frame to the GIF
    Input: frameNode* head: The head of the linked list ( The first frame of the GIF )
           newFrame*: The new frame to be added
    Output: None
*/
void addFrame(frameNode* head, frameNode* newFrame)
{
    frameNode* current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) // <-- Exception thrown here
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newFrame;
    newFrame->next = NULL;
}
```

I suppose that the problem lays somewhere in the creation of the linked list, but i cant put my finger on it.

I'll add anything else you guys need if asked. And I know that questions similar to this has been asked before, I checked them and it seems to not help my cause.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Log all your calls to `createFrame` to see if the issue is with parsing the file or with managing the linked list. Once you find out which is the issue, remove all the code not needed to replicate the problem. (If the problem is with the linked list, we'll need to see the code for `createFrame` and `addFrame` at a minimum. Give us just enough code to replicate the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `counter` is keep on incrementing and never meets your conditions.

> Read my comments inline.

```
if (counter == 0)
{
    strcpy(name, line);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
   counter++; //increment the counter **kiran**
}
if (counter == 1)
{
    strcpy(path, line);
    path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = 0;
   counter++; //increment the counter **kiran**
}
if (counter == 2)
{
    atoi(line);
    sleep = line;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        *head = createFrame(name, path, sleep);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = createFrame(name, path, sleep);
        addFrame(&head, temp);
    }
    counter = 0; //reset the counter
    i++;
}
    //memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
    //memset(path, 0, sizeof(path));
   // counter++;   //remove this line    **kiran**
```

---

Update to handle second issue.

```
  addFrame(&head, temp);
```

should be

```
addFrame(*head, temp);
```

As of now you are passing `frameNode ***` but it should be `frameNode *`.

Comment: @xTheMoonLigherx007 Maybe you need one more coffee break, that's it.

Comment: Well Oof :| Now I'm getting an access violation which says: Exception thrown: read access violation.
current was 0x2C2DE900. :( Gotta Get a break lol

Comment: @xTheMoonLigherx007 We will be needing [mcve] for that problem.

Comment: Sure, I'll Add The New code and the addFrame function rn

Comment: Okay wow your right :| Now I want to cry lol :( Thanks a lot buddy! really appreciate that

Comment: Explaining A bit more about the cause of the problem would be nice :D